# SELECT subquery with 2 return values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to select multiple columns from a subquery. Here my minimal example:

A **function** that returns two values:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dummy_function(my_text text)
RETURNS TABLE (id Integer, remark text) AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY SELECT 42, upper(my_text);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

My **not working query**:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    city_name, 
    dummy_function(city_name)
FROM 
    (SELECT 1 as id, 'Paris' as city_name
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 2 as id, 'Barcelona' as city_name
    ) AS dummy_table
```

My **wrong result**:

```
 id | city_name | dummy_function 
----+-----------+----------------
  1 | Paris     | (42,PARIS)
  2 | Barcelona | (42,BARCELONA)
```

But **I would like to have a result like this**:

```
 id | city_name | number |   new_text
----+-----------+---------------------
  1 | Paris     |  42    |   PARIS
  2 | Barcelona |  42    |   BARCELONA
```

Do you know how to achieve this without running the function twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the function returning row (or set of rows) in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT 
    dummy_table.id, 
    city_name, 
    dummy_function.id,
    remark
FROM 
    (SELECT 1 as id, 'Paris' as city_name
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 2 as id, 'Barcelona' as city_name
    ) AS dummy_table,
    LATERAL dummy_function(city_name)

 id | city_name | id |  remark   
----+-----------+----+-----------
  1 | Paris     | 42 | PARIS
  2 | Barcelona | 42 | BARCELONA
(2 rows)
```

Per [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html):

> Table functions appearing in FROM can also be preceded by the key word LATERAL, but for functions the key word is optional; the function's arguments can contain references to columns provided by preceding FROM items in any case.

Comment: It works :-)
But in the answer below I get the same result, but without using `LATERAL`.
Why should I use `LATERAL` in this case?

Comment: See the adited answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    dummy_table.id, 
    city_name, 
    df.id as number, 
    df.remark as new_text
FROM 
    (SELECT 1 as id, 'Paris' as city_name
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 2 as id, 'Barcelona' as city_name
    ) AS dummy_table,
    dummy_function(city_name) df
```

Comment: Add `dummy_table.` to `id`, because it exists in both `dummy_table` and `dummy_function`

Comment: It works :-)
But in the answer above I get the same result, but with the use of `LATERAL`.
Why do you not need `LATERAL`?

Comment: `lateral` is optional for functions. It will cause an error in older versions.